# Avoid division by zero between matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

I'm using matlab and I have two matrices :

```
G =

 1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1
```

and the scond:

```
m =

 4     4     4     4
 0     0     0     0
```

I want this result :

```
x =

 1/4     1/4     1/4     1/4
  0       0       0       0
```

What I did so far is this :

```
x = G ./ m
```

But it returns :

```
x =

 1/4     1/4     1/4     1/4
 NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

How can I avoid the divison by zero by placing a default value "0" if there is a division by zero ?

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the NaNs back to zero:

```
x = G ./ m;
x(isnan(x))=0;      % thanks to comment by @nkjt
```

Or, if you have also NaNs in matrix `m` that you want to save, you can do:

```
x(m==0)=0;
```

Comment: Caution - you cannot locate `NaN`s in the normal way (try `NaN==NaN` at the command line).  You should use `isnan` instead (or your second suggestion should work fine).

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to preallocate `x` and then only use division on the parts where `m` is not zero.

```
x = zeros(size(m)); % output is same size as m
n = m~=0;  % find indexes
x(n)=G(n)./m(n);
```