# :Inf x 1 divided by :Inf x 1 yields :Inf x :Inf Matlab

Tags: matlab

My post is related to the following questions:

[Avoid division by zero between matrices in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122456/avoid-division-by-zero-between-matrices-in-matlab)

[How to stop MATLAB from rounding extremely small values to 0?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/117149-how-to-stop-matlab-from-rounding-extremely-small-values-to-0)

I am writing a matlab function that I am exporting with **codegen**. When codegen executes division between two numbers, both primitive doubles, codegen mentions that the result is a type of :Inf x :Inf. Here is my code snip:

```
travel_distance = stop_position - start_position;
duration = stop_time - start_time;
velocity = (travel_distance / duration);
```

Neither travel_distance or duration variables are zero. During codegen, when I examine the variables of travel_distance and duration, they are both :Inf x 1. However, velocity is showing as :Inf x :Inf . This is being shown also for the (travel_distance / duration) block of code. I suspect that I am running into the scenario mentioned by the author in the second link, which mentions this quote:

> MATLAB will not change the value to 0. However, it is possible that the result if using the value in an operation is indistinguishable from using 0

I've tried several things to try and solve my problem, and am still getting the same thing. For example:

```
% increment by a small number
velocity = ((travel_distance + 0.0001) / (duration + 0.0001));

% check if nan, and set to 0
velocity(isnan(velocity)) = 0;

% check if nan or inf and set to 0
if (isnan(velocity) || isinf(velocity))
    velocity = 0;
end
```

I'd actually expect that the travel_distance, duration, and velocity are all of type 1x1, since I know these should be primitive results.

What can I do to ensure matlab performs codegen correctly, by allowing the velocity variable to be either an :Inf x 1 or a 1x1? ( Double or Int output is fine )

Comment: Did you try using `./` instead of `/`? I'm guessing that `:Inf x 1` refers to a vector of unknown length, and `:Inf x :Inf` to a matrix of unknown size. This has nothing to do with division by zero.

Comment: That works. I wonder why? Not sure why my matrix is of an unknown size. It should always be a 1x1.

Comment: Codegen might not be able to assure itself of that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I suppose that might be the case. Abstraction. Thanks for the quick reply. Please leave it as the answer, so I can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is related to division by zero, as shown by the attempts you made at avoiding that. `:Inf x 1` refers to a vector of unknown length, and `:Inf x :Inf` to a matrix of unknown size. If `duration` is a vector, then `travel_distance / duration` is trying to solve a system of linear equations.

If you use `./` (element-wise division) instead of `/`, then Codegen might be able to generate the right code:

```
velocity = travel_distance ./ duration;
```